# How to install Canon Pixma E400 on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: drivers, printing, 14.10, canon, pixma

Fair warning: I am a complete noob to Linux and Ubuntu.

I have been trying to install the Canon Pixma E400 printer but have not succeeded so far.

I tried:

- locating the driver through the built-in Printer Settings option, but there wasn't any driver available for my printer (found one for PIXMAE500, installed that but it did not work).
- The generic driver for pdfs also did not work; my printer didn't take any jobs through that driver.
- installing the driver from the .exe file that came with the setup disk of the printer, but `wine` did not recognise that file.
- Downloaded the [binary .deb file](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100396801.html) but it didn't work either.
- I downloaded the [relevant driver packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9F06.png) (tar.gz) from the web, extracted them, read through the [README](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcPCZ.png) file in there, but could not figure out its instructions. I then tried to execute the three-step compilation process, having changed to the extracted directory (via CD), suggested here to get an error saying `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`.

I could not find any duplicate questions and have tried the usual solutions I found here. I am probably missing some basic detail due to my ignorance about Ubuntu.

*Could someone here advise me how to handle this?*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what is the exact URL where you downloaded this printer module? (A.k.a. "driver")

Comment: I downloaded it from here: http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100396801.html

Comment: You've put a ton of work in there already, ;-) and I have a Canon Pixma too, but for me the standard driver worked (though I still have to calibrate it as it's printing too dark). So: I'll try to compile the driver for you and get back to you after that.  (I added that the binary driver didn't work either, so if my assumption is incorrect, drop me a note @Fabby)

Comment: I've found: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-print/  and will have a look at that first...

Comment: I admit defeat: no way of installing this printer under Ubuntu.  How old is it???  (and even worse: I fiddled so much with my system that I have to restore a system back-up, as my own Canon isn't working any more)

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Fabby! I just got the printer about 2 weeks ago. I had another system with Windows7, so didn't care much with checking its compatibility with Ubuntu 14.10. Unfortunately, that system got physically damaged before the printer arrived! :-|

Comment: The only thing I can do for you is upvote your question.  If you haven't had an answer in a week, drop me a note again.

Answer (score 0):

Download the driver here. http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100588102.html
I have e400 too, tested and working on Ubuntu Server 14.04. I didn't check scanner options yet.

Answer (score -1):

I just downloaded the E400 driver from the support-asia site and loaded three of the four drivers that came from the unzip.  The printer now works on Linux Mint Rosa 17.3.

As I am new to linux I don´t know how it did it.  I downloaded the file then used GDebi package installer.  Used it to unzip and then added the printer.  Everything just happened properly.

I really miss DOS.  At least with that I knew what was happening.

Comment: "I don't know how it did it," isn't very helpful as an answer, unfortunately.  OP provided a lot of steps, and was still stuck.  It's important to outline as many details and specifics as possible for someone having trouble as they are.